First Time Content not getting triggered instantly
My App Starts here ...

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController

    private val promptManager by lazy {
        BiometricAuthentication(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            navController = rememberNavController()
            SetupNavGraph(navController = navController, promptManager = promptManager)
        }
    }
}


Onboarding
@Composable
fun OnBoarding(navController: NavController, viewModel: FirstTimeViewModel) {
    val isFirstTime by viewModel.isFirstTime.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary) {
        when (isFirstTime) {
            null -> {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                        color = Color.Blue
                    )
                }
            }

            true -> {
                // First time launch
                OnBoardingScreenHorizontalPager(navController)
            }

            else -> {
                // Non-first time launch
                NonFirstTimeContent()
            }
        }
    }
}

OnBoardingScreenHorizontalPager composable goes onto call a series of composables but thats not important for this question it will eventuallly call RegisterName Composable.
NavHost
@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    promptManager: BiometricAuthentication
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screens.Onboarding.route
    ) {
        composable(route = Screens.Onboarding.route) {
            OnBoarding(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel())
        }
        composable(route = Screens.OnboardingRegistration.route){
            RegisterUserPage(navController = navController, promptManager = promptManager)
        }
        
         composable(route = Screens.NonFirstTime.route){
      RegisterName(viewModel = viewModel())
        }
     }
}


Here Is RegisterName Composable
@Composable
fun RegisterName(
    viewModel: FirstTimeViewModel
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                viewModel.onFirstTime()
            },
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(26.dp),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                containerColor =  colorResource(id = R.color.onboarding_green)
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(200.dp)
                .height(50.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.continue_registration),
                fontFamily = montserratFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.W800,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.white)
            )
        }
    }
}


After the button is pressed nothing happens but after i relaunch the app after closing, it gets to  NonFirstTimeContent() composable from Onboarding Composable. How do i make it instant ?
heres the data store handling code as well
// SettingsDataStoreManager.kt 
private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")

class SettingsDataStoreManager(context: Context) {
    private val dataStore = context.dataStore

    suspend fun setFirstTime(isFirstTime: Boolean) {
        dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[isFirstTimeLaunchKey] = isFirstTime
        }
    }

    fun isFirstTimeLaunch(): Flow<Boolean> =
        dataStore.data.map { pref ->
            pref[isFirstTimeLaunchKey] ?: true
        }

    companion object {
        private val isFirstTimeLaunchKey = booleanPreferencesKey("isFirstTime")
    }
}

// FirstTimeViewModel.kt
class FirstTimeViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val dataStore = SettingsDataStoreManager(application)

    val isFirstTime: StateFlow<Boolean?>  = dataStore.isFirstTimeLaunch()
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
            initialValue = null,
        )

    fun onFirstTime() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            dataStore.setFirstTime(false)
        }
    }
}



I cannot reproduce the issue. I tried to get your code to work by filling in the blanks and removing everything that didn't seem necessary. The resulting code works as expected. Please [edit] your question to replace your code with a [mre] that can be executed and actually exhibits the problematic behavior in a reproducible manner.

@tyg i have attached NavHost as well hopefully that should give more clarity. And when you mean its not reproducible you were able to see the behaviour instantly ?. If after looking at the NavHost code and its the same behaviour can you show your code snippet somehow so that i can take a look into it ?

Please reduce your code to a [mre] that we can execute. Remove everything that is not strictly necessary to reproduce the issue and make sure everything that is needed to compile and run the code is actually there. Just create a new project and copy the code of the question to see what is missing. Then when you got it to compile start removing as much as possible while still retaining the problematic behavior. Then remove all code from this question and replace it with the minimal version you just created. As it is now the question attracks answers that are just guessing.

okay ill reduce the code even further down @tyg please give me some time

@tyg i have polished the content please take a look into it

An important part is still missing: "OnBoardingScreenHorizontalPager [...] will eventuallly call RegisterName." -- How? Please also provide this code. And what are NonFirstTimeContent and RegisterUserPage? If they are not important then please remove them and their navigation destinations entirely.

1- Create interface
interface SettingsDataStore{
    suspend fun putBoolean(key : String,value: Boolean)
    suspend fun putString(key : String,value: String)
    suspend fun putInt(key : String,value: Int)
    suspend fun getBoolean(key : String) : Boolean?
    suspend fun getString(key : String) : String?
    suspend fun getInt(key : String) : Int?
    suspend fun deleteBoolean(key : String)
    suspend fun deleteString(key : String)
    suspend fun deleteInt(key : String)
    suspend fun clearPreferences()


}

2- Implement it
    class SettingsDataStoreImpl(
    private val context: Context
    ) : SettingsDataStore {
    override suspend fun putBoolean(key: String, value: Boolean) {
        val preferenceKey = booleanPreferencesKey(key)
        context.dataStore.edit {
            it[preferenceKey] = value
        }
    }

    override suspend fun putString(key: String, value: String) {
        val preferenceKey = stringPreferencesKey(key)
        context.dataStore.edit {
            it[preferenceKey] = value
        }
    }

    override suspend fun putInt(key: String, value: Int) {
        val preferenceKey = intPreferencesKey(key)
        context.dataStore.edit {
            it[preferenceKey] = value
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getBoolean(key: String): Boolean? {
        val head = context.dataStore.data.first()
        val preferenceKey = booleanPreferencesKey(key)
        return head[preferenceKey]
    }

    override suspend fun getString(key: String): String? {
        return try {
            val head = context.dataStore.data.first()
            val preferenceKey = stringPreferencesKey(key)
            head[preferenceKey]
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return null
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getInt(key: String): Int? {
        return try {
            val head = context.dataStore.data.first()
            val preferenceKey = intPreferencesKey(key)
            head[preferenceKey]
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return null
        }
    }

    override suspend fun deleteBoolean(key: String) {
        val preferenceKey = booleanPreferencesKey(key)
        context.dataStore.edit {
            if (it.contains(preferenceKey)){
                it.remove(preferenceKey)
            }
        }
    }

    override suspend fun deleteString(key: String) {
        val preferenceKey = stringPreferencesKey(key)
        context.dataStore.edit {
            if (it.contains(preferenceKey)){
                it.remove(preferenceKey)
            }
        }
    }

    override suspend fun deleteInt(key: String) {
        val preferenceKey = intPreferencesKey(key)
        context.dataStore.edit {
            if (it.contains(preferenceKey)){
                it.remove(preferenceKey)
            }
        }
    }

    override suspend fun clearPreferences() {
        context.dataStore.edit {
            it.clear()
        }
    }


}


3- Create the module
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesSettingsDataStore(@ApplicationContext context: Context):  SettingsDataStore {
        return SettingsDataStoreImpl(context)
    }
}

4-Create the events
sealed class SettingsEvent {
    data object SetFirstLaunch : SettingsEvent()
    data class SetDarkMode(val darkMode: Boolean?) : SettingsEvent()
    data class SetAmoledTheme(val amoledTheme: Boolean) : SettingsEvent()
    data class SetDynamicTheming(val dynamicTheming: Boolean) : SettingsEvent()
}

5-Create the State
data class SettingsState(
    val firstLaunch : Boolean = false,
    val darkMode : Boolean? = null,
    val amoledTheme : Boolean = false,
    val dynamicTheming : Boolean = false
)

6- Create the view model
class SettingsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val settingsDataStore: SettingsDataStore
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(SettingsState())
    val state = _state.stateIn(
        viewModelScope,
        SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
        SettingsState()
    )

    var setKeepOnScreenCondition: Boolean = true

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val firstLaunch =
                async { settingsDataStore.getBoolean(SettingsConstants.FIRST_LAUNCH) ?: true }
            val darkMode = async { settingsDataStore.getBoolean(SettingsConstants.DARK_MODE_TYPE) }
            val amoledTheme =
                async { settingsDataStore.getBoolean(SettingsConstants.AMOLED_THEME_TYPE) ?: false }
            val dynamicTheming = async {
                settingsDataStore.getBoolean(SettingsConstants.DYNAMIC_THEME_TYPE) ?: false
            }

            _state.update {
                it.copy(
                    firstLaunch = firstLaunch.await(),
                    darkMode = darkMode.await(),
                    amoledTheme = amoledTheme.await(),
                    dynamicTheming = dynamicTheming.await()
                )
            }
            setKeepOnScreenCondition = false
        }
    }

    fun onEvent(event: SettingsEvent) {
        when (event) {
            SettingsEvent.SetFirstLaunch -> {
                viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    settingsDataStore.putBoolean(SettingsConstants.FIRST_LAUNCH, false)
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            firstLaunch = false
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

            is SettingsEvent.SetAmoledTheme -> {

            }

            is SettingsEvent.SetDarkMode -> {

            }

            is SettingsEvent.SetDynamicTheming -> {

            }
        }
    }

}

7-MainActivity
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val settingsViewModel: SettingsViewModel by viewModels()

    @Inject
    lateinit var settingsDataStore: SettingsDataStore

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge(
            statusBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.light(
                Color.TRANSPARENT,
                Color.TRANSPARENT
            )
        )
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition { settingsViewModel.setKeepOnScreenCondition }

        setContent {
            val firstLaunch = runBlocking { settingsDataStore.getBoolean(FIRST_LAUNCH) ?: true }
            val settingsState = settingsViewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
            ExibhiteaseTheme {
                ExibhiteaseApp(
                    firstLaunch = firstLaunch,
                    settingsViewModel = settingsViewModel,
                    finishActivity = {
                        finish()
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }


}


Please [edit] your answer to describe in more detail how this addresses the specific problem op has. To me it looks just like a code dump of some random data store implementation, unrelated to the problem at hand.

Your answer isn't addressing the problem in the question.
